# How to a load video file by using OpenCV with C++ on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

I run the code (as below) that can play video stream on windows platform(Visual Studio 13 C++).
The code compile successfully on Raspberry Pi but it can not show video.
The video file is in the same document. I had try `VideoCapture cap('/home/pi/1.mov')` that also doesn't work.
How should I modify the code?

PS. If `VideoCapture cap("1.mov")` change to `VideoCapture cap(0)` which open USB camera successfully.

Thanks!

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    Mat frame;

    VideoCapture cap("1.mov");

    if (!cap.isOpened())
        cout << "Error when reading stream";

    namedWindow("Frame", 1);
    for (;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
            break;
        imshow("Frame", frame);
        if (waitKey(10) >= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Result: `Error when reading stream`

Comment: Are you really sure you have the right filename? Including upper/lowercase?

Comment: Yes, the filename is right.

Comment: Try with absolute path @CaseyWang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install proper codecs. See a similar question (and code) here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/9692/mp4-reading/